# Send copy of order confirmation email, based on customer data, to different email addresses

Tags: magento

Magento: Based on certain customer data I need to send a copy of the confirmation email to other email addresses.

I created an observer to catch the order data

```
checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
```

In my observer class I load all data I need with

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($observer->getOrderIds());
```

That works like a charm.

Now some code is selecting the email address where the copy supposed to go to.

But how can I send a copy of the order confirmation email to (always different) email addresses?

```
$order->sendNewOrderEmail();
```

Above doesn’t work for me because I need the recipient as a parameter.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This question relating to development or usage of Magento should be asked on [magento.se]

Comment: Didn't know that. Thank you. I'll transfer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to create your own order class:

```
class My_Mymodule_Model_Sales_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order {

    public function sendNewOrderCustomEmail($email) {
        // copy from parent's sendNewOrderEmail method with changed this line
        // $emailInfo->addTo($this->getCustomerEmail(), $customerName);
    }
}
```

And then in your event, use

```
Mage::getModel('mymodule/sales_order')
->load($order_id)
->sendNewOrderCustomEmail('myemail@...');
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento takes emails from order data.
Try:

```
$order->setCustomerEmail("new@email.com");
$order->sendNewOrderEmail();
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I guess, I would have to run save() to get it work. But I don't want to overwrite the original customer email. - Thanks for the tip.